# String matching/searching for python

Tags: python, regex, wikipedia, pywikibot

I'm attempting to scrape and clean wikipedia data.  I have a data field that contains dimensions as shown below.

```
["112 x 76 yards (102.4m x 69.4m)", "104.5 x 70.3 m", "107m x 72m", 
 "109×73 yds / 100×67 m", "{{convert|105|x|68|m|yd|1}}", "100 metres by 70 metres"]
```

Extracting the dimensions is easy enough, but extracting the unit is rather difficult given how many variations of entries there are.
What is the best way to approach this?

I have started by using;

```
"(\d+\.?\d*)"
```

Which should extract all the dimensions, I was then going to save only the first 2 numerical matches, save the first match of a unit('m','metre','metres','y','yard','yds','yd','ft'.....) and then I can convert all to metres later.

I am just unsure about how I would go about saving the first unit match.

Comment: You could supply an array of the unit strings you want to match and match against it, then hash by index with the dimensions.

Comment: possibly helpful or related [Regular expression extracting number dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44555769/regular-expression-extracting-number-dimension)

Comment: [Related](https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). Also, if parsing is ambiguous, you can use the implied conversion rate to hopefully rule out some options.